# WebGL to background

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript for WebGL and I implemented in a website. But it renders on top of the html elements like logos and texts. Is there a script to send to background?

Answer (score 0):

Put your html elements after the canvas element.
Also use absolute positioning on them. 
Make sure the z-index of the canvas is smaller than other elements.

This simple html,css question doesn't relate to webGL i guess.

Good luck.

Comment: It was my fault. Put the z-index on the wrong one. Thanks.